# Как после отправки формы вывести красивый блок с текстом об успешной отправке и далее сделать переадресацию на главную страницу?

Tags: php, форма

Нужно чтобы после отправки формы, пользователю выводился блок с текстом об успешной отправке формы, не знаю как это реализовать на php и вообще возможно ли это

Comment: Это не реализуемо на php. Вам нужно в любом случае использовать js, будь то ajax или без него

Answer (score 1):

Надо использовать `ajax` запросы к серверу, чтобы получить ответ в формате `json`. На `javascript` реализовать вывод окна с текстом ответа, например использовать `bootbox`. Сам PHP не сможет вывести окно адекватно, так или иначе надо использовать клиентскую часть. Лично я в проектах использую `bootbox` и отправку `ajax` запросов на сервер с получением `json` ответа.

Comment: _чтобы получить ответ в формате json_ а если я хочу ответ в формате xml?..

Comment: Сделайте просто заголовок в формате xml: `header("Content-Type: text/xml");` - как вариант. А как вы XML собираетесь возвращать на клиент и с ним работать - это как-то очень странно.

Comment: Ну я это так, к слову, спросил.. Просто вы утвердительно пишите _чтобы получить ответ в формате json_, хотя формат данных зависит от сервера, есть и api которые тот же xml отдают.. Будь я совсем новичком меня это ввело бы в заблуждение

Comment: @InDevX скажу так, что личное мое мнение об API, которые отдают XML формат - не нормальные. Хотя бывают случае, когда надо XML. Просто сами посудите, если вам с сервера на клиент вернется XML, то вам удобно будет на JS с ним работать? Лично я считаю, что лучшее решение для таких задач - JSON ответы. Это связано с тем, что JS умеет работать с JSON как с ассоциативным массивом.

Comment: О не нормальных, это всё-равно что назвать человека 1-80 карликом... Вы с api не работали толком, если считаете что они отдают на клиент что-то)

Comment: @InDevX Раз вы такой умный, то почему бы самому не написать ответ. Стоит задача - вывести клиенту блок информации. Я подсказал о том, что на сервере работает скрипт с API и как-то его обрабатываете, а ответ необходимый отправляете на клиент в формате JSON, чтобы вывести предупреждение. С клиента обращение к себе на сервер, который обращается к API и далее по списку. Судя по вашим ответам - вы новичок и не видите сути решения, воспринимая все прямолинейно.

Comment: У меня нет никаких задач, вы явно что-то путаете. Этот комментарий лучше вашего ответа получился - так и надо сразу писать, чего я и "добивался" своими вопросами. А по ответам да, действительно новичок, пошел поплачу

Comment: @InDevX отпишитесь потом по результатам